# Python Pandas: fill a column using values from rows at an earlier timestamps

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe *df* where one column is *timestamp* and one is *A*. Column *A* contains decimals.

I would like to add a new column *B* and fill it with the current value of A divided by the value of A one minute earlier. That is:

```
df['B'] = df['A']_current / df['A'] _(current - 1 min)
```

**NOTE:** The data does not come in exactly every 1 minute so "the row one minute earlier" means the row whose timestamp is the closest to (current - 1 minute).

Here is how I do it:

First, I use the timestamp as index in order to use *get_loc* and create a new dataframe *new_df* starting from 1 minute after *df*. In this way I'm sure I have all the data when I go look 1 minute earlier within the first minute of data.

```
new_df = df.loc[df['timestamp'] > df.timestamp[0] + delta] # delta = 1 min timedelta

values = []
for index, row n new_df.iterrows():
  v = row.A / df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(row.timestamp-delta,method='nearest')]['A']
  values.append[v]

v_ser = pd.Series(values)
new_df['B'] = v_ser.values
```

I'm afraid this is not that great. It takes a long time for large dataframes. Also, I am not 100% sure the above is completely correct. Sometimes I get this message:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
>   using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

What is the best / most efficient way to do the task above? Thank you.

PS. If someone can think of a better title please let me know. It took me longer to write the title than the post and I still don't like it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide some reproducible data and code, in other words a **[mcve]**.

Comment: @jpp will do, sorry I'm in the middle of something with a tight deadline. I thought for now the explanation was clear enough, will update later. Thank you

Comment: I think your explanation is clear, but without data it's hard to test a solution and benchmark performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use .asof() if the DataFrame has been indexed correctly by the timestamps (if not, use .set_index() first).

Simple example here

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
n_vals = 50

# Create a DataFrame with random values and 'unusual times'
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(low=1,high=6, size=n_vals),
                  index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start=pd.Timestamp.now(), 
                                         freq='23s', periods=n_vals), 
                  columns=['value'])

# Demonstrate how to use .asof() to get the value that was the 'state' at 
# the time 1 min since the index. Note the .values call
df['value_one_min_ago'] = df['value'].asof(df.index - pd.Timedelta('1m')).values

# Note that there will be some NaNs to deal with consider .fillna()
```